# How can I set a web server directory for an extension_dir in php.ini?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

Currently I am doing a web based PHP project which is connected with SQL Server with **sqlsrv** method in php. The frame work is CI, and I use **php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll** extension to connect the SQL Server like (**extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll**) in php.ini. It works in my local client without any issue.

But I needed to host the web site in my shared web server, the SQL Server is already connect with an IP address.

How can I do this?

I tried in below method, but it gives error:

**method 01**

I uploaded all the dll files in web server and I changed the extension_dir as

**extension_dir=http://example.uk/myweb/sqlsrv_dll_files/**

**method 02**

I uploaded all the dll files in web server and I set the extension path as

**extension=http://example.uk/myweb/sqlsrv_dll/php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll**

But this gives below error:

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in **C:\xampp_v5\htdocs\web_project\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php on line 144**

**A PHP Error was encountered**

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Filename: sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php

Line Number: 144

Backtrace:

---

Please advice me to rectify this error.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Firstly: Is your "shared hosting environment" windows or linux? Secondly: Contact your hosting provider to enquire about the availability of this extension on their platform.

Comment: It is a shared Linux server

Comment: Then [DLL's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) have no place in a linux environment. Plus those full URL's won't work, you'd need local file system paths.

Comment: Is there any tutorials to do this local file system?